# My battery has corroded at the red and black connectors

Tags: toyota, camry, jump-start

As seen in the picture my batter in a 2012 Toyota Camry has this white salt-like build up around the bracket that holds the battery in place. However, there is no tea build up in the red and black terminals.

Another thing to note is that the white substance has spilled over onto the base of the battery as well.

Is this a sign of a leak? Should I be replacing the battery or just clean the corrosion and jump start the car?

Any help is appreciated!

[image: Image shows corrosion build up and spillover]

[image: Another angle of the corrosion build up]

Comment: And once you have done what the answer says, then do the cleaning at each service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rinse with plenty of water then sprinkle on baking soda . The white is zinc and iron sulfate .Caused by sulfuric acid ,liquid or vapor,  getting out of the battery . No practical way to stop it. I would continue to use it but a new battery will fix it. You may need new nuts and bolts for the hold down and the terminal connections will need a good cleaning when you get a new battery.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I will do as you say. I got the battery out but like you mention the bolts are stuck to it. Will try to rinse and get them unstuck.